# How to accessing docker-compose CLI

Tags: airflow

I installed airflow with docker-compose. And I'd like to create user admin for authentication on web-UI of airflow. How can i go to the CLI for create it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the command from one of the running airflow-* services (containers) defined in the docker-compose file you got from Airflow. One way of doing it is by using `docker-compose run`, for example, to run `airflow info` command do:

`docker-compose run airflow-worker airflow info`

Where `airflow-worker` is the name of the service (could be any other of the Airflow services) and `airflow info` is the CLI command.

If you want to create a [new user](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#create_repeat1) the CLI command is:

```sh
airflow users create [-h] -e EMAIL -f FIRSTNAME -l LASTNAME [-p PASSWORD] -r
                     ROLE [--use-random-password] -u USERNAME
```

So to create an user do:

```sh
docker-compose run airflow-scheduler airflow users create --username adminn --password admin --firstname Admin --lastname User --role Admin --email admin@superhero.org
```

If you are on Linux o Mac OS there is a shortcut to run commands in this containers by using a script provided by Airflow, check the [docs here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.1/start/docker.html#running-the-cli-commands) if you are insterested.

**Note**: By default, the official docker-compose installation takes care of creating an user with admin privileges:

username: *airflow* // pass: *airflow*

This is done during the [airflow initialization](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.1/start/docker.html#initialize-the-database) process.